# Opening JOptionPane with focus after JComboBox selection

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, joptionpane

I am having a problem with a `JComboBox` and a `JOptionPane` dialog.
The situation is this:

- It needs to run from a Dialog, not a Frame
- Before data is set no check needs to be done
- After data is set changes need to be validated

I have a JComboBox with initial data in it and I have an `ActionListener` which, on selection, displays a `JOptionPane` dialog with a warning about revalidating.

When a selection is made the dialog appears as normal but the `JComboBox` doesn't finish it's cycle and keeps the `JComboBox` open until the dialog is clicked and then you need to do a further click to choose an option (regardless whether the first click is on top of the button).

```
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import java.awt.Frame;
 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
 import javax.swing.JDialog;
 import javax.swing.JComboBox;
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
 import javax.swing.UIManager;
 import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

 public class DialogFocus extends JDialog {

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      private JPanel jContentPane = null;
      private JComboBox jComboBox = null;

      public static void main(String[] args) {
           new DialogFocus(null);
      }

      /**
       * @param owner
       */
      public DialogFocus(Frame owner) {
           super(owner);
           initialize();
           setLookAndFeel();
           this.setVisible(true);
      }

      public void setLookAndFeel() {
           try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
           } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
           }
      }

      /**
       * This method initializes this
       * 
       * @return void
       */
      private void initialize() {
           this.setSize(300, 200);
           this.setContentPane(getJContentPane());
      }

      /**
       * This method initializes jContentPane
       * 
       * @return javax.swing.JPanel
       */
      private JPanel getJContentPane() {
           if (jContentPane == null) {
                jContentPane = new JPanel();
                jContentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                jContentPane.add(getJComboBox(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
           }
           return jContentPane;
      }

      /**
       * This method initializes jComboBox     
       *      
       * @return javax.swing.JComboBox     
       */
      private JComboBox getJComboBox() {
           if (jComboBox == null) {
                String[] items = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
                jComboBox = new JComboBox(items);
                jComboBox.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                     public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                          showDialog();
                     }
                });
           }
           return jComboBox;
      }

      protected void showDialog() {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Selection made");
      }

 }
```

The code I am using is quite complex so I have thrown together a basic example of code here. With the look and feel set it required 2 clicks to click on a valid option but without it it required a single click. (*Comment out `setLookAndFeel()` in  the constructor*).

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this to make sure it only requires 1 click regardless of the look and feel?

Thanks in advance

Comment: i don't understand your question but you want setPopupVisible(false) when actionPerformed executed?

Comment: I want the popup to only require a single click (rather than 1 click for focus, and another for "OK") to complete. Without using invokeLater()

Comment: instead of actionListener did you try itemListener?

Comment: Yes. I gives me the exact same result. The JComboBox locks and i need to click to give JOptionPane the focus

Comment: i think camickr answer is correct, if you wrap your call in invokeLater the showDialog call later

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the code in an invokeLater to let the combo box repaint itself before the dialog is shown:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        showDialog();
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried that, unfortunately there is a boolean set in another part of the class which is being called set beforehand (even when invoke later is used on that too) and that in turn causes problems

Comment: This suggestion works on the code you posted. If it doesn't work in your class then you need to post a better SSCCE. We know nothing about this Boolean field that you are talking about. Take the concepts learned here and apply them to your real problem. Maybe you need to add another invokeLater() somewhere in your code to let the comboBox repaint itself before the dialog is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

From an inner class, to access a variable in the outer class, you need to reference ComboBox.this.myBool. Often, you can just do myBool if it's unambigious.

```
public class ComboBox {

    private boolean myBool = false;

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            boolean myBoolAgain = ComboBox.this.myBool;
            showDialog();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar problem implementing an ItemListener for a JComboBox, which asks the user a question after a ItemEvent.DESELECTED event, if a certain condition is met. Since the ItemListener implementation may revert selection based on user's answer, dispatching a new Runnable to EDT was not an option - the JOptionPane with the question needed to be shown inside the ItemListener, which manifested the problem OP described.

JComboBox'es popup holds focus when shown even if a subsequent modal dialog is created and displayed, so you need to hide it before showing the JOptionPane, using [`JComboBox.hidePopup()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#hidePopup--). Doing this gives the resulting dialog focus when shown as expected and no double-clicking is required.